# GridFS and Sailsjs

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, gridfs

In order to create a new GridFS instance, a database should be provided

```
var grid = new Grid(db, 'fs');
```

How can I get the database without reconnecting (thinking of something like sails.db or sails.adapter-mongo.db) ?

Comment: is there any news for this?

Comment: No, changed to AWS storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to sailsjs but I had similar problem with mongodb 
so, I started to dig into sails source code and found this. (please correct me if I'm wrong)

Each sails model you create(generate) is bound with connection object.
This defines adapter that whatever you config in adapter config file.

Referring to sails doc "custom adapter"

Custom-adapters must have properties pointing db instance.

In summary, you can access it through

YourModelName.connections.dbNameFromConfigfile

e.g.

adapter.js (0.9) or connection.js (0.10.x)

```
module.exports.connections = {


  someMongodbServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    // user: 'username',
    // password: 'password',
    database: 'fileDb'
  },



};
```

File.js (Model)

```
module.exports = {

}
```

FileController.js (Controller)

```
module.exports = {
  upload: function(req, res){
    var db = File.connections.someMongodbServer;  // name at config file


     your code here....

  }

}
```

Comment: Any more info on this? I wasn't able to instantiate a gridfs instance using this method.